# error when importing database to site

Tags: php, mysql

When I'm trying to import my database to my site through a `.sql` file, I always get an error and I don't know what to make of it.

I will post the error below.

> There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser. 
>   Please examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are
>   correct  and not mis-matched. Other possible failure causes may be
>   that you are  uploading a file with binary outside of a quoted text
>   area. You can also  try your query on the MySQL command line
>   interface. The MySQL server  error output below, if there is any, may
>   also help you in diagnosing the  problem. If you still have problems
>   or if the parser fails where the  command line interface succeeds,
>   please reduce your SQL query input to  the single query that causes
>   problems, and submit a bug report with the  data chunk in the CUT
>   section below:

```
----BEGIN CUT----
eNodjTsOwjAUBKnfKfYAwYo/EHBnRU5AcmJjh0+PKCJF7pDg9jjUM7NrY/RRo+VoBZwdNTgEVHPc
15SmQjZEwzddnMaOcdbI7XNZ6JoifKpgejtOFW62iPc5oztH2/kHJGc1hcFoqBIdKJzCKlU+rTOK
CQk35/eHnBl7jVem/8MPI0shyQ==
----END CUT----
----BEGIN RAW----

ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 1 2 47960
STR: 

MySQL: 5.1.73-cll
USR OS, AGENT, VER: Win FIREFOX 31.0
PMA: 4.1.8
PHP VER,OS: 5.4.23 Linux
LANG: en
SQL: 

----END RAW----
```

The actual error message is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to     your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'U' at line 1

First lines from the .sql:

```
USE [kal_auth]
GO
/****** Object:  User [kal]    Script Date: 08/11/2014 14:44:15 ******/
CREATE USER [kal] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[kal]
GO
/****** Object:  Schema [kal]    Script Date: 08/11/2014 14:44:04 ******/
CREATE SCHEMA [kal] AUTHORIZATION [kal]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CNum]    Script Date: 08/11/2014 14:44:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CNum](
[UID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Num] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_CNum] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: Can you please add the first line of the .sql file you're trying to import?

Comment: Added first lines in main post.

Comment: This code looks for SQL Server, not MySQL...

Comment: It is for SQL, but i selected MSSQL compatibility on phpMyAdmin when i tried to import this. Also, the hosting provider said MSSQL is enabled, just not very popular.

Comment: Do you even know what [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) is?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't found a bug in the SQL parser. You're simply trying to run SQL Server code in MySQL.

---

The SQL acronym refers to a computer language used to query relational databases. Products that can speak SQL often include SQL on their names (MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL...) but that's all, a name. The term itself represents a *language*, not a specific product.

The SQL language is useful because it doesn't belong to a single vendor. However, each vendor implements its own dialect. You simple cannot run arbitrary SQL on an arbitrary system.

> the hosting provider said MSSQL is enabled, just not very popular

MSSQL is **not** an option inside MySQL. It's an entirely different piece of software.

Comment: If so, then how am i supposed to import the database?

Comment: Rewrite your application to use SQL Server or rewrite the SQL dump for MySQL, whatever suits your needs/resources better.

Comment: i have migrated the databases from SQL server to MySQL and created another set of .sql files for the site. Upon trying to import them, i now get this error.

     MySQL said:
#1044 - Access denied for user 'fantasia'@'localhost' to database 'kal_auth_dbo'

Comment: That's an entirely different problem. And it's just what the message says.